# Faulting module Qt5Core.dll

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, timestamp, executable

I am using the PyQt 5.15.xx library for our executable software. Unfortunately, on some computers, some antivirus programs trigger the following error. I don’t know how to solve this issue. I would be very happy if somebody has any idea:

[image: Error Message:]